# Homology of wegde sum, exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I am solving an exercise: showing that for two CW complexes $X$ and $Y$ the homology of the wedge sum $X \vee Y$ can be expressed as direct sum. This has already been solved elsewhere here. My question is this: The solution of the exercise states that the sequence:

$$ 0 → H_k (X) → H_k (X ∨ Y) → H_k (Y) → 0 $$

is exact for all $k$. I believe this to be wrong for $k = 0$ because in this case the boundary morphism:

$$ H_1(Y) → H_0 (X) $$ 
is not zero because this is actually 
$$H_1(Y/\{x_0\in X ~ x_0 \in Y\}) \to H_0(X)$$

X and Y share one $0$-cell in the wedge.

Am I correct?

Comment: What is this boundary morphism $H_1(Y)\to H_0(X)$? And what is $Y/\{x_0\in X, x_0\in Y\}$?

Comment: @Berci Ah should have explained it more clearly. I mean in the long exact sequence of relative homology. I can build the sequence: $\cdots \to H_n(X \vee Y, X) \to H_{n-1}(X) \to H_{n-1}(X \vee Y) \to H_{n-1}(Y) \to \cdots$ because as CW complexes $(X\vee Y,X)$ is a good pair.

Comment: ah, and also noting that $H_*(X\vee Y,X) = H_*(X \vee Y / X)$

Comment: You need to look at reduced homology instead to make this statement true.

Comment: @apurv ok good thanks, that is what I thought :)